# Splash login issue on NYT

Tags: authentication, lua, screen-scraping, hidden, scrapy-splash

It seems I cannot pass the login page of nytimes.com

My LUA script is:

---

```
function main(splash, args)
  --splash:init_cookies(splash.args.cookies)

  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(2))
  assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  local url = splash.args.url
  assert(splash:go(url))
  assert(splash:wait(1))

  splash:set_viewport_full()

 --  local search_input = splash:select('#username') 
 -- search_input:send_text("MyUsername")

  token = splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('authToken').value")

  splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('authToken').value = '"..token.."';")
 --token = splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('authToken').value")
 splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('username').value = 'MyUsername';")
 username =  splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('username').value")
  assert(splash:wait(1))
 splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('password').value = 'MyPassword';")
password =  splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('password').value")
assert(splash:wait(1))
splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('rememberMe').value = 'F';")
assert(splash:wait(1))
--local submit_button = splash:select('#submitButton')
submit_button = splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('submitButton')")
assert(splash:wait(10))
submit_button:click()
assert(splash:wait(2))
return {
  cookies = splash:get_cookies(),
  html = splash:html(),
  png = splash:png(),
  har = splash:har(),
  hidden_token=token,
  username=username,
  password = password,
}
end
```

---

I used this directly on the Splash browser with the login page:

https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login

The fields (username, password and hidden) can be accessed, and are populated with the correct data. The button click works  (or so it seems) but the result takes me to the same login page and advise me to register.

The #rememberMe checkbox is checked and this script cannot change its status. I am not sure this is contributing or not to failing to login.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Reassigning the token value to the same value has no particular purpose. I wanted to check what values are in the inputs. If the code works it should work without these 2 lines:          token = splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('authToken').value")

  splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('authToken').value = '"..token.."';")

Comment: I corrected the rememberMe checkbox issue. Instead of assigning the value I added a click event like this:----------- rememberMe = splash:evaljs("document.getElementById('rememberMe')")
  assert(splash:wait(1))
  rememberMe:mouse_click() ------- Also this code was moved before the username and password value set because it was resetting these values to null.

Comment: I tried with Selenium and Chromium and they both work on the Chrome browser, using the same fields and values.

Comment: I tried with a different user name and password and it works the same (just to make sure the charachters like @ and _ do not have a role in this). I also tested the code on a gmail.uncc.edu account, instead of nytimes account and it works just fine. I printed the values to check for errors and added a loop to make sure the submit button is not clicked before the username and password fields are populated, still no change. I am running out of options. Suggestions anyone? Thanks